# Integrating Azure SSO / External Users

Tags: asp.net, azure, single-sign-on

I’ve integrated SSO successfully many times into web projects, however the end users have always been part of a companies domain in Azure.

I’ve a requirement for a legacy asp.net to allow logins via azure SSO. Typically not a problem, however this is a B2B scenario and the primary company offering the application wishes to allow permitted companies to login via SSO from their own azure ad, so licensing aside in terms of permitted companies, is this possible? Everything I’ve tried so far hasn’t quite worked so I’ve a feeling I’m missing an step. To further complicate matters, there’s also a winforms application which also requires SSO, It currently utilizes an asp.net identity database which both apps share.

Any pointers on this one would be greatly received

Comment: Have you looked at Azure AD [External entities](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/active-directory/external-identities/)

Comment: Both your web and desktop app can be registered as Azure AD app, and then use this Azure AD based [SSO approach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant)

Answer (score 0):

> however this is a B2B scenario and the primary company offering the
> application wishes to allow permitted companies to login via SSO from
> their own azure ad, so licensing aside in terms of permitted
> companies, is this possible?

Basically it won't be possible as per what you are trying to do ,
Until and unless you can provision your application for federation in that tenant. Thus i would recommend you to make your internal application publicly available for federating with other partner Azure AD environment. Once your application becomes publicly available to your partner companies, You can ensure that your application federation metadata gets imported in your partner comapanies `Azure AD` and its configured for `SSO` . Thus your partner companies can access that application through SSO Authentication by their own Azure AD .

Since your application would be a non-gallery application please refer the below link for how to configure non-gallery application with Azure AD.

- BLOG: https://docs.wire.com/how-to/single-sign-on/azure/main.html
- MS DOC: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-howto-app-gallery-listing